# jQuery datepicker and fullcalendar, datepicker not showing

Tags: jquery, datepicker, fullcalendar

When i include datepicker component and fullcalendar component into layout File,
datepicker is not wokring. but, each page is working correctly one by one.
plae help me.
code here:
**Calendar.jsp**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>calendar</title>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://arshaw.com/css/main.css?6' />
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://arshaw.com/css/fullcalendar.css?3' />
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href="fullcalendar.css" />
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.6.3/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.6.3/jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.6.3/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
<script>
$(function() {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                                    //
                    });
</script>
```

**datepicker**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function() {

    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();

    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat","yy-mm-dd");

    $.datepicker.regional['ko'] = {
               ...
             };
                 $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['ko']);
 });
</script>
```

**layout.jsp**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1">
<!-- datepicker input text part -->
<tr height="300px"><td><%@ include file = "./datepicker.jsp" %></td></tr>

<!-- Jquery fullcalendar part -->
<tr><td><%@ include file = "./Calendar.jsp" %></td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am unable to see your code, can you try again please?

Comment: i paste it. can you see it?

Comment: I think problem is javascript function... i already use onload function $(document).ready(function() but still not working

Comment: I can see it now... let me have a look at datepicker.jsp and calendar.jsp

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are including the `JS` files in your `Calendar.jsp` but the `datepicker` is found in `Layout.jsp` so when `Calendar.jsp` is loaded, it does not know anything about where `datepicker` is.

Try moving all your includes for JS and CSS files to your `Layout.jsp`

I put this fiddle together and it seems to work:

http://jsfiddle.net/2faxr/